# Can I omit braces for a hash in a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash in a hash:

```
validates :password,
        length: { within: 5..30 },
        presence: true
```

Is it possible to omit the braces for a hash in a hash? This:

```
validates :password,
          length: within: 5..30,
          presence: true
```

raises a syntax error.

Comment: Those are braces, not brackets or brakets.

Comment: Suppose you had `h = {a:b, {c:d, e:f}, {e:g}}` and wanted to extract the values `f` and `g`, i.e., `h[{c:d, e:f}][:e]` and `h[{e:g}][e]`.  If one could omit parentheses, this would become `h = {a:b, c:d, e:f, e:g}`, but since hashes cannot have duplicate keys, `e:f` or `e:g` would have to go. Even if the last hash were `{h:g}`, how could Ruby possibly know how to extract keys and values from `{a:b, c:d, e:f, h:g}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More accurately, you have a Hash literal within a Hash literal that happens to be the last argument in a method call. The only time you can leave out the braces is when the Hash is the last argument in a method call, they are required everywhere else. Your inner Hash is a value in another Hash literal and that's not the last argument in a method call so, no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not (at least that I know of) since length takes multiple parameters and expects a hash as an argument.  One thing I've found myself doing is initializing these constraints in my config/constants.rb file since these variables don't change all that often and I often find myself providing multiple parameters to length.

config/constants.rb

```
MODEL_LENGTH_CONSTRAINT = {
    within: 5..30,
    too_short: "must have at least %{count} words",
    too_long: "must have at most %{count} words"
}
```

app/models/model.rb

```
validates :password,
    length: MODEL_LENGTH_CONSTRAINT,
    presence: true
```

I know it's not really a solution to your problem, but it's a little cleaner IMO.  Happy coding.